# Entity Framework 6 code-first migrations generation

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, migration

I want to be able to selectively run SQL commands genereted by Entity Framework 6 migration, so I could alter or filter them. So ideally I would have some code like this :

```
var migration = EF.GetMigrationOperations();
var filteredOperations = migration.Where(...);
SqlContext.ExecuteCommands(filteredOperations);
```

This is just a pseudocode describing my desire. So is there any way to do this ? I have not found one yet. Usecase for this is for automated db migrations e.g. filter DROP statements until new version of app is uploaded.

Comment: I am afraid, there is no direct way to achieve this. Someone please correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved it partially. To get at least .sql script in code I used https://romiller.com/2012/02/09/running-scripting-migrations-from-code/ with basic context factory. Another way to get sole operations in code as initially requested would be to use brutal reflection on `HistoryRepository` class of EntityFramework.